# Where are the math.h functions?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, include, cygwin

I am interested in seeing how math.h functions such as sin(),cos(), pow(,), log(),... are carried out. The math.h files within my Cygwin and MinGw folders seem only have function declarations {such as extern double cos _PARAMS((double));}. Where are the actual function definitions located?

Comment: After some quick googling, take a look at [this](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/math_8h_source.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208488/implementation-of-math-functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541130/definitions-of-sqrt-sin-cos-pow-etc-in-cmath

Comment: I'm not asking how use the functions from math.h. Rather, I am interested in knowing how they are made (such as with Taylor series)

Comment: Err, the question which this is marked as duplicate of doesn't seem to have anything to do with this question. Instead this seems to be duplicate of the questions linked by Cyber.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is that sine and cosine are implemented in microcode inside microprocessors

You may also check [this](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD)

Comment: My company is looking for new processors.  Can you list some processors that have instructions (assembly) that calculate since and cosine?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews:- The version for Intel x86 processors is written in assembly. It simply uses the FPU's built-in fsin instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Math functions may be in the compiler's executable, so there may be no code to show.

There are Free Software examples of compiler code.  I suggest you take a look at the GNU compiler source code for some examples.

Processor manufacturers may also have some implementations, *that are platform specific to maximum use of their processor*.