# Calculating square root for extremely large numbers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, limits

I am solving some tasks from school olimpiads, and I got stuck on one question. I found the solution for the task, but my solution requires square rooting. My code works fine for first 12 inputs, but then it gives wrong answers. I guess that it is due to extremely large inputs, which can be as large as 10^400000. So I would like to know if there are ways to calculate whole number parts of square roots of these extremely large inputs in C. Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    long long n;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    long long ans;
    ans = sqrtl(n-1);
    long long result;
    result = ans+1-llabs(n-ans*ans-(ans+1));
    printf("%lld\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "extremely large". Do you mean greater than 2^64? If so you can't do this with a `long long` and you'll need some kind of [bignum library](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: The idea of such a challenges is not to use builtin `sqrt` functions but use your own algorithm.

Comment: @tadman: 10**400000 is probably higher than that :)

Comment: @tadman in the task it is said input can be as large as 10^400000

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I may not be good at math but I think it has a very high probability of being too big for a 64-bit int.

Comment: very high like 100% :)

Comment: You're going to have to research square root algorithms and implement your own solution if you're not allowed to use third party libraries. See also [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581528/how-is-the-square-root-function-implemented).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm going to go with 99.99999999...% just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @tadman: better safe than sorry. That said, `sqrt(10**400000) = 10**200000`.

Comment: 10 ** 400000 is approximately `542101086242752217003726400434970855712890625000[...399930 zeroes redacted...]000` times larger than the maximum value that would fit `uint64_t`.

Comment: As large as *10^400000*?!  Are you sure you don't mean `10^40`?  Values that large *cannot* be represented in native types, not even `long double`.  You're going to have to use a third-party bignum library, or learn how to implement one of your own.

Comment: @chrisz no, 10^400000 is just restriction, input can be any number between 1 to 10^400000

Comment: @JohnBode I would even ask how one can have it as an input..

Comment: @EugeneSh. 400k digits? That easily fits in a string.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Don't we all have a couple of hours to type in up to 400000 digits?

Comment: @JohnBode Unfortunately, it is 10^400000.

Comment: @arkang: Yee ha.  You're going to want to look at [this](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Is the number being expressed in 10^n notation? If so this could be pretty easy.

Comment: @tadman no, if it was 10^n that indeed would be easy

Comment: Even if you have to roll your own, I'd be absolutely sure to check against a reference implementation like GMP.

Comment: @tadman i'll definetely check

Comment: @tadman How long do you think such a calculation will take with GMP (just curious, never worked with it)? Anyway, I am pretty sure that the OP have misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My guess would be instant. I don't see what's so outlandish about the assignment.

Comment: @melpomene It depends on the algorithm used and the efficiency of the bignum representation. There's a binary search approach that shouldn't be too punishing.

Comment: @tadman Eh? It's just `mpz_sqrt(result, input);`.

Comment: "but then it gives wrong answers."  --> Post the number inputted, result and expected result.

Comment: @chux the problem is that inputs are unknown

Comment: Post samples from the  "My code works fine for first 12 inputs, ", especially ones that give "wrong answers.".

Comment: @chux the user can see the results for the inputs (correct, time limit error or incorrect answer) and time consumed to execute, but not the input or answer itself

Comment: Why does code use `abs(int)` instead of the correct `llabs(long long int j)` -  Is that the problem?

Comment: @arkang You coding goals _must_ have some description as to the syntax, range of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: oh, I forgot to fix it here, because I copied from notepad, but when I sent the answer I used llabs, so it is not the problem

Comment: @arkang  Any other fictional code? - Post your true code.  suggest cut and paste.

Comment: @chux Do you think it will help? Because the aim of the question is not to get solution to the task I am doing, but just to get some ideas on how to deal with these crazy numbers.

Comment: @arkang Yes it will help.  The trouble is that you have only _described_ the crazy numbers and have not posted their results nor expected output.  Posting true sample inputs, output and expected output is a great assist.  Lacking that, the post lacks useful information.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you can roll a long square root algorithm by the dichotomic method as follows:

- choose a long number representation (array of unsigned ints);
- implement long addition and subtraction (pretty trivial, except for carries);
- implement halving (also requires some care for carries);
- implement long comparison (similar to subtraction).

[Note that addition allows you to implement doubling and quadrupling, and halving also yields division by four.]

Then set `d= 1` and repeatedly double `d` until `d² > N`. (Every time you double `d`, you quadruple `d²`.)

Next, set `a= 0` so that the invariant

```
a² ≤ N < (a + d)²
```

is established, and repeatedly halve `d` while keeping the invariant. This is achieved by

`d= d/2;` if `N ≥ (a + d)²`, set `a= a + d`; else keep `a` unchanged.

In the end, you will narrow down to

```
a² ≤ N < (a + 1)²
```

so that `a` is the integer square root.

To evaluate the condition

```
N < (a + d)² = a² + 2ad + d²,
```

or

```
N - a² < 2ad + d²,
```

it suffices to keep a trace of the terms `N - a²`, `2ad` and `d²` and update them as you modify `d` or `a`. This only takes the aforemetioned primitive operations.

Comment: It seems the conditional is inverted, if N is less than (a + d)² then a should not be incremented by d.

Comment: @jeje: you are right. Thanks for reporting the typo.