# How do programs calculate square roots?

Tags: c++, math, square-root

I understand that this is a pretty math-y question, but how do programs get square roots? From what I've read, this is something that is usually native to the cpu of a device, but I need to be able to do it, probably in c++ (although that's irrelevant).

The reason I need to know about this specifically is that I have an intranet server and I am getting started with crowdsourcing. For this, I am going to start with finding a lot of digits of a certain square root, like sqrt(17) or something.

This is the extent of what python provides is just `math.sqrt()`

I am going to make a client that can work with other identical clients, so I need complete control over the processes of the math. Heck, this question might not even *have* an answer, but thanks for your help anyway.

[edit]
I got it working, this is the 'final' product of it:  (many thanks to @djhaskin987)

```
def square_root(number):
    old_guess = 1
    guess = 2
    guesssquared = 0
    while round(guesssquared, 10) != round(number, 10):
        old_guess = guess
        guess = ((number / guess) + guess ) / 2
        print(guess)
        guesssquared = guess * guess
    return guess

solution = square_root(7) #finds square root of 7
print(solution)
```

Comment: From googling the title of your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots .  I don't suspect that you will find a convenient way of parallelizing the task, if that's what you are describing.  Known methods seem to iterate on an answer to produce a _slightly better answer_.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of algorithms you can use to find square roots if you don't like the one in the standard libraries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: "_...std::sqrt is required by the IEEE standard to be exact..."_ - source https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: The thing is, I am trying to make it able to be divided among multiple clients.

Comment: I think what I need is a structure of code that demonstrates how it is done by the computer.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you want an algorithm that computes a *lot* of digits for some cryptographic needs?

Comment: A lot of architectures provide square root at the hardware level. [Example](https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_116.html).

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to implement anything for me. But looked all over the place and I couldn't find how square roots were actually calculated.

Comment: I understand that square root functions are provided, but I need to have control over the design of the algorithm.

Comment: Are you asking how to optimize square root calculation in C++?

Comment: Not exactly, I just need to be able to control it

Comment: In your own code just don't use `std::sqrt` but use your own implementation. This is how you will control it in your code.

Comment: @TylerGlen not sure what sort of control you need such that the __exact__ guarantee  is insufficient?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing your own square root function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623375/writing-your-own-square-root-function)

Comment: Oh, right. Proposing a dupe on a question with two close votes closes it. Sorry. For your reference, some more answers: [How is the square root function implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581528/how-is-the-square-root-function-implemented)

Comment: Yes that's great! @djhaskin987's answer worked for me, with a little debugging.

Comment: The question was closed, but I added a solution in the edit (sorry it's a little messy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers use a method that people have actually been using [since babylonian times](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/05/16/babylonian-square-roots.html):

```
def square_root(number):
    old_guess = 1
    guess = 2
    while old_guess != guess:
        old_guess = guess
        guess = ((number / guess) + guess ) / 2
    return guess
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work. I think it needs something to keep the 'guess' variable changing, I thing it's doing the same thing over and over.

Comment: it's because `check != number` is not strictly accurate. if guess is not changing, it's because it's arrived at the answer but float rounding is defeating us @TylerGlen

Comment: Very very good, but pay attention passing a number below 0. Doing it, you can also block your entire program...

Answer (score 1):

x86 has many sqrt in registry, starting with [FSQRT for float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings).

In general, if your function is too complicated or has no implementation, and is [C^\infty](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-InfinityFunction.html) ("infinitely" differentiable), you can expand it into a polynom via [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). This is extremely common in HPC.