# Why `x = x*(1.5f-(xhalf*x*x));` can be a Newton Method iteration?

Tags: algorithm, math, square-root, newtons-method

Ok, by far, I guess many people know the famous [fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) (see more on [Writing your own square root function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623375/writing-your-own-square-root-function) and [0x5f3759df](http://blog.quenta.org/2012/09/0x5f3759df.html))

Here is the code

```
float FastInvSqrt(float x) {
  float xhalf = 0.5f * x;
  int i = *(int*)&x;         // evil floating point bit level hacking
  i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);  // what the fuck?
  x = *(float*)&i;
  x = x*(1.5f-(xhalf*x*x)); // one Newton Method iteration
  return x;
}
```

---

Ok, i do NOT need to know more how magic `0x5f3759df` is.

**What I don't understand is why `x*(1.5f-(xhalf*x*x))` is a `Newton Method` iteration?**

I tried analyse but just can't get it.

So let's assume r is the real number and x is the inverse sqrt of r.

`1 / (x^2) = r`, then `f(x) = r*(x^2)-1` and `f'(x) = 2 * r * x`

So one iteration should be `x1 = x - f(x)/f'(x) = x / 2 + 1 / (2 * r * x)`, right?

**How comes `x * (1.5 - ((r / 2) * x * x))`?** (note I replaced `xhalf` with `r / 2` here)

---

**Edit**

Ok `f(x) = x^2 - 1/r` is another form, let me calculate

`f(x) = x^2 - 1 / r`

`f'(x) = 2 * x`

So `x1 = x - (f(x)/f'(x)) = x - (x^2 -(1 / r))/(2*x) = x / 2 + 1 / (2 * r * x)`, still it is quite different from the formula used in the code, right?

Comment: I take it that this is in C/C++ in an environment where `int` and `float` are both 32 bits?

Comment: I feel that the links you've provided do a decent job of explaining what's going on behind the scenes here...

Comment: @Makoto It doesn't explain why that is an iteration of newton method

Comment: Wikipedia explains Newton's method here. It uses different function. `f(x) = 1/x^2 - r` in your terms.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Newton-Fourier_method would be my suggestion for the formula you are missing.

Comment: @zch if you do `f = 1 / x^2 -r` once, you will know it is still different

Comment: @JacksonTale, it seems ok to me. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia says function is (using your variable names):

> f(x) = 1/x<sup>2</sup> - r

Then we have:

> f'(x) = -2/x<sup>3</sup>

And iteration is:

> x - f(x)/f'(x) =
>
> x - (1/x<sup>2</sup> - r)/(-2 / x<sup>3</sup>) =
>
> x + x<sup>3</sup> /2 * (1/x<sup>2</sup> - r) =
>
> x + x/2 - r/2 * x<sup>3</sup> =
>
> x * (1.5 - r/2 * x * x)

And this is what you see in code.

Comment: I got it wrong that f'(x) should be `-2/(x^3)` instead of `1/(x^3)`

Answer (score 3):

[Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is defined in terms of the iteration

> x<sub>i+1</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> - f(x<sub>i</sub>) / f'(x<sub>i</sub>)

(where f'(x) is the first derivative of f(x)). To find the inverse root of r, one needs to find the zero of the function f(x) = x - 1/sqrt(r) (or, equivalently, f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> - 1/r). Simply take the derivative, plug it in to the definition of the iteration step, simplify, and you have your answer.

Actually, the exact form used in the code comes from using a third equivalent form:

> f(x) = x<sup>-2</sup> - r

See [this article](http://rrrola.wz.cz/inv_sqrt.html) for the detailed steps of the derivation. It's also derived in the [Wikipedia article on fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

Comment: @JacksonTale - See [this page](http://rrrola.wz.cz/inv_sqrt.html) for a derivation of the last step. It comes from a third (equivalent) form of the function: x^(-2) - X.