# Sqrt function working in c

Tags: c, sqrt

How does sqrt function really work ? Does  it  go  by  any  logical  theorem   to  get  the     result.

Is there any way i can access the code of libarary function such as sqrt?

Comment: This would more be a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's in the GNU library. Source code is readily available.

Comment: look http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html

Comment: There are lots of algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRootAlgorithms.html). There are also answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623375/writing-your-own-square-root-function

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=math/s_csqrt.c;hb=HEAD

Comment: can i access the file? on my pc

Comment: Can I use google to find answers on the web ? (Sorry I just couldn't resist ;-) )

Comment: thnx! ur info was valuable

Comment: @AntonH [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: @gnat Given that it's a question about the conception of a language, I really don't see the point of your comment. If you could give more detail, I would be happy to read your answer.

Comment: @AntonH see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6484/31260

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the source code from the libc, which is open source: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi

Comment: This has a lot of very good information on the different ways to implement the sqrt function, and their speeds and precision