# Radius of an Ellipse at a given angle with given length and width

Tags: c, math, trigonometry

I am writing a function in C that returns the radius of an ellipse at a given angle with a given length and width; Basically writing this calculation in C:

[image]

Unfortunately the platform does not support `math.h` however there are `sin` and `cos` functions built in that I can use.

How do I write this calculation in C and store it in an `int`?

I have tried:

```
int theta = 90;
int a = 164;
int b = 144;

float aa = (((a^2) * ((sin_lookup(DEG_TO_TRIGANGLE(theta)))^2)) +
            ((b^2) * ((cos_lookup(DEG_TO_TRIGANGLE(theta)))^2))) /
           (TRIG_MAX_ANGLE^2);

float result = (a * b) / (my_sqrt(aa));
int value = (int)result;
```

Comment: Does it have `sqrt`?

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: Have you attempted anything? If so, please post it.

Comment: `^` in C doesn't do what you expected. [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843304/995714). For the square root you can [writing your own square root function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1623375/995714)

Comment: show what you tried in the `my_sqrt` function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy enough

```
int getRadius(double a, double b, double theta)
{
     double s = sin(theta),
            c = cos(theta);
     return (a * b) / sqrt((a*a)*(s*s)+(b*b)*(c*c))
}
```

Though I'm not sure why you want to return an `int`. You'll loose a lot of precision.

---

The `^` operator is not the way to do powers. It's actually a bitwise XOR. This is a common mistake new (C) programmers make. `math.h` has a function `pow()` for calculating powers, but you said you can't use `math.h`. These values are only raised to the second power, so it's pretty easy to just multiply it manually.

Comment: instead of creating 2 double values I would use macro or make my own pow() function. Just suggestion otherwise I think your answer is perfect.

Comment: @GRC If `pow` isn't already defined, that's probably a good way to do it, but just in case their math library defined `pow`, I avoided it.

Comment: Probably want the return as `double` -- `int` really isn't that exciting (not to mention integer math and all....)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The question specifically requested `int`, otherwise I completely agree. `int` isn't going to tell you a whole lot.

Comment: I gotcha, just seems so counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks @PCLuddite! I used a slightly modified version of your code, and it only returns an approximation.  However that is all I needed. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/chrisschlitt/cf9b77c64492ca376e54
Also, I had to use an int because the draw command I was using to draw a line required integers as an input