# for loop increment with decimal stopping at 1.42 instead of continuing until calculation is complete

Tags: javascript

I have developed a simple little square root calculator within **JavaScript**, using a `for` loop.

However, I noticed when outputting each value for `i` every time the loop iterates (using `console.log(i).toFixed(2)`), the counting would stop at `1.42` every time.

Here is the **JavaScript**:

```
// inp is the input in which the user types the number they would like to find the square root of
for(var i = 0; i < inp.value; i += 0.01){
    var check = i * i;
    check = check.toFixed(2); // fix decimal to a tenth

    console.log(i.toFixed(2)); // output value to console

    if(check == inp.value){ // if i * i is equal to user input
        alert(i); // alert the square root
        break; // break out of for loop
    } else if(check > inp.value){ // if the value is more than user input
        alert("Value could not be found."); // alert value could not be found 
        break; // break out of for loop
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated, 
Thanks.

**EDIT**: I have noticed that if I am to type in `1`, it will output up until `0.99`, as opposed to `1.42`

**EDIT No 2**: I tested out Ibrahims new answer, and it semi-sort of worked. It now stops at `3.17`, instead of `1.42`. However, I noticed that after testing it out, my laptops fans would start spinning at full throttle, and my CPU load would spike to 100% for a brief second, before slowing to about 40%. Would it perhaps be the fact the laptop cannot handle the consistent for loop? If so, what would be a better alternative to this? Thanks

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pk7or60f/

Comment: what is your inp.value value?

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN whatever the user inputs.

Comment: whatever the user inputs you stop at 1.42?

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN yep!

Comment: I just tried your code it's not stoping on `1.42`? Give some inputs and their outputs! Try and type `10` in your input, it will stop at `3.17`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I've tried so many numbers and 10 was one of them and it popped out the same thing

Comment: You're probably not using the right `inp.value` or you'r not calling the code right! Post a complete fiddle of your code!

Comment: that works for me too

Comment: Fiddle posted..

Answer (score 1):

I had doubts about it but it was the error all along. `.toFixed` is returning a string (that's I know), `inp.value` is a string (that's I know too). But I thought that since `>` work with just numbers, that the interpretter will use their values as numbers and do the right comparison. But I was wrong about that. So to force the interpretter to see them as number, use the **explicit** way using `Number` or `parseFloat` like this:

```
else if(Number(check) > Number(inp.value)){
    alert("Value could not be found.");
    break;
}
```

or the **implicit** way using the `unary +` like this:

```
else if(+check > +inp.value){
    alert("Value could not be found.");
    break;
}
```

The same goes for equality check.

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Thanks for the answer

Comment: Hi, I'm trying it now, it's semi-fixed my problem in that in now stops at `3.17`, instead of `1.42`

Comment: @GROVER.  at any given input!

Comment: @GROVER. if you're really stubborn about reinventing the square root function, then check this two link: [**same question on stackoverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623375/writing-your-own-square-root-function) and [**wikepedia page on the same topic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots). I hope your hair won't grey!