# Integer ceil(sqrt(x))

Tags: math, integer, square-root

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624602/10005302) gives the following code for computing `floor(sqrt(x))` using just integers. Is it possible to use/modify it to return `ceil(sqrt(x))` instead? Alternatively, what is the preferred way to calculate such value?

Edit: Thank you all so far and I apologise, I should have make it more explicit: I was hoping there is more "natural" way of doing this that using `floor(sqrt(x))`, possibly plus one. The `floor` version uses Newton's method to approach the root from above, I thought that maybe approaching it from below or similar would do the trick.

For example the answer even provides how to round to nearest integer: just input `4*x` to the algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `x` is an exact square, the ceiling and the floor of the square root are equal; otherwise, the ceiling is one more than the square root. So you could use (in Python),

```
result = floorsqrt(x)
if result * result != x:
    result += 1
```

Modifying the code you linked to is not a good idea, since that code uses some properties of the Newton-Raphson method of calculating the square root. Much theory has been developed about that method, and the code uses that theory. The code I show is not as neat as modifying your linked code but it is safer and probably quicker than making a change in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fact that:

```
floor(x) = (ceil(x) - 1) if x \not \in Z else ceil(x)
```

Hence, check if `N` is in the form `2^k`, the code is the same, and if it is not, you can `-1` the result of the current code.